# Can python extract text within repeated specific characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

Is it possible to extract text contained in a specific character set {} when it is repeated multiple times in the string?

```
string = 'Revenue for the period is {value="32", font="34"} and EBITDA is {value="12", font="34"} for 2022'
```

The output should contain the instances as elements in a list in string format.

```
output = ['{value="32", font=34}', '{value="12", font=34}']
```

Comment: It was not supposed to, I have edited this to reflect the true output. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re` to apply a regex pattern to match text in curly brackets:

```py
import re

# Dont use str (a built-in class) as a variable name
string = 'Revenue for the period is {value="32", font="34"} and EBITDA is {value="12", font="34"} for 2022'

output = re.findall(r'{[^}]+}', string)
```

```
>>> output
['{value="32", font="34"}', '{value="12", font="34"}']
```

Note that `output` will be an empty `list` if there are no matches

> Online demo: https://regex101.com/r/XB7U9g/1
>
> My reccomendation for learning regex patterns: https://regexone.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [re.findall()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

```py
import re

text = (
    'Revenue for the period is {value="32", font="34"} and EBITDA is {value="12", '
    'font="34"} for 2022'
)
pattern = re.compile(r'{value="\d+", font="\d+"}')
print(re.findall(pattern, text))
```

Output:

```py
['{value="32", font="34"}', '{value="12", font="34"}']
```